# Is this possible that one objects follows the other object's transformation?

Tags: modeling, groups

I'm trying to make an animation of tessellation structure.
Since I have to edit bunch of units at the same way, I wonder if it is possible to edit only one object and set others just follow the first one automatically. I have tried Parenting, Grouping etc but I haven't found any solution yet. Thx in advance!

Comment: Make a copy using Alt+D (original and copy will have the same shared inner geometry)

Comment: Also the "copy transforms" constraint could be useful, maybe.